# Query returns empty result in PHP,but works fine on phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysqli

Can you help me with something? This is my code, that should return values from an MYSQL DB. The problem is that when I print the result (array) it's empty.

```
$query = 'call test("Ingreso","Ventas Exportación",2015,1,6,"Ventas Expo")';
echo $query;
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

(
[sum_ppto] => 
[sum_real] => 
[sum_real_ytd_pasado] => 
[ppto_anual] => 
[ppto_meses_restantes] => 
)
```

But when I do the exact same query, without the parameters, the array is filled with the information.

```
$query = 'call test2()';
echo $query;
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
(
    [sum_ppto] => 2987676043
    [sum_real] => 3115640330
    [sum_real_ytd_pasado] => 2843994399
    [ppto_anual] => 5217552938
    [ppto_meses_restantes] => 2101912608
)
```

Where is a picture when I run the routine (test) in phpmyadmin
[image: Click Here]

Here is a picture of the other routine (test2)
[image: Click here]

The procedure is this

```
select 
(select 
sum(Valor) 
from 
registro
where 
Anio_idAnio=year and
Mes_idMes between mes_inicio and mes_termino and
idReal_Ppto = (select idReal_Ppto from real_ppto where Real_Ppto = "Ppto") 
and 
idArea_Negocio=(select idArea_Negocio from area_negocio where Area_Negocio = 
area_negocio_input) and 
idNom_CC = (select idNom_CC from nom_cc where Nom_CC=nom_cc_input) and
idG_Cta = (select idG_Cta from g_cta where G_Cta=g_cta_input)) 
    as sum_ppto,
(select 
sum(Valor) 
from 
registro
where 
Anio_idAnio=year and
Mes_idMes between mes_inicio and mes_termino and
idReal_Ppto = (select idReal_Ppto from real_ppto where Real_Ppto = "Real") 
and 
idArea_Negocio=(select idArea_Negocio from area_negocio where Area_Negocio = 
area_negocio_input) and 
idNom_CC = (select idNom_CC from nom_cc where Nom_CC=nom_cc_input) and
idG_Cta = (select idG_Cta from g_cta where G_Cta=g_cta_input)) 
    as sum_real,
(select 
sum(Valor) 
from 
registro
where 
Anio_idAnio=year-1 and
Mes_idMes between mes_inicio and mes_termino and
idReal_Ppto = (select idReal_Ppto from real_ppto where Real_Ppto = "Real") 
and 
idArea_Negocio=(select idArea_Negocio from area_negocio where Area_Negocio = 
area_negocio_input) and 
idNom_CC = (select idNom_CC from nom_cc where Nom_CC=nom_cc_input) and
idG_Cta = (select idG_Cta from g_cta where G_Cta=g_cta_input))
    as sum_real_ytd_pasado,
(select 
sum(Valor) 
from 
registro
where 
Anio_idAnio=year and
Mes_idMes between 1 and 12 and
idReal_Ppto = (select idReal_Ppto from real_ppto where Real_Ppto = "Real") 
and 
idArea_Negocio=(select idArea_Negocio from area_negocio where Area_Negocio = 
area_negocio_input) and 
idNom_CC = (select idNom_CC from nom_cc where Nom_CC=nom_cc_input) and
idG_Cta = (select idG_Cta from g_cta where G_Cta=g_cta_input))
    as ppto_anual,
(select 
sum(Valor) 
from 
registro
where 
Anio_idAnio=year and
Mes_idMes not between 1 and mes_termino and
idReal_Ppto = (select idReal_Ppto from real_ppto where Real_Ppto = "Real") 
and 
idArea_Negocio=(select idArea_Negocio from area_negocio where Area_Negocio = 
area_negocio_input) and 
idNom_CC = (select idNom_CC from nom_cc where Nom_CC=nom_cc_input) and
idG_Cta = (select idG_Cta from g_cta where G_Cta=g_cta_input))
    as ppto_meses_restantes
```

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Is `mysqli_fetch_assoc($ejecuta_query);` a typo in your question? Shouldn't it be `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);`?

Comment: It must be a copying error, otherwise he wouldn't get anything in `$row`.

Comment: It's an error of typing. I fix it and still doesn't work

Comment: Can you show the `test()` procedure? Does it have multiple `SELECT` queries?

Comment: Yes, it does. At least 5 subqueries

Comment: try add `mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")` before `$query`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is working, or you would not get the key names when you run the CALL.

So the problem must be in the selection clause.

The only plausible cause I see is that one of the parameters, `"Ventas Exportación"`, gets mangled by a wrong charset mapping due to that "o" in Esportacion, and makes the `SELECT` return nothing.

As a quick fix you can try and replace the = clause with a LIKE, and pass "Ventas Esportac%" as a parameter. Or see whether some other values may be used that do not contain accented characters. If this way it does work, try then checking which charsets come into play.

The fix suggested by user @Rainmx93:

```
try adding mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8") before $query
```

I've met all kinds of troubles with mismatched Latin1 (the MySQL default in my installations) aka ISO-8859-1(5), CP-1282, and UTF8. Rows not being correctly selected is pretty common. You might need to change the collation of your database (do a backup first).

Comment: Another user said something similar in comments. I change the charset to utf8 and worked properly. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I have made the answer a community answer, I don't like when it looks like I'm cribbing :-) -- I'll still delete this one if @RainMx93 posts an answer of their own, but otherwise you should mark the answer as accepted, so that it may be useful to the next guy passing by.

Comment: @LSerni for me it's okay if Nicolas will accept your answer because you explain why it doesn't work and how to fix it, and i write only comment without any explanation.